# Exclude child components from <div onclick>

Tags: html, reactjs, onclick

I render multiple 'div' which the user can select by clicking on it with a simple onClick:

```
<div onClick={() => this.handleTrackerCardClick()}>
```

However the user can also edit a field displayed on the 'div' by clicking on a button. In this case I don't want the 'div onClick' to be called, because obviously the user wants to use the Edit function and not to select the 'div'.

See the following example:

- The user can click on the green area to select the 'div'
- If the pencil (in red area) is clicked, I don't want the call the 'div onClick'

[image]

Is this possible?

Thank you!

Comment: Note that div elements are not designed to be interactive so you've introduced accessibility problems here. For example, it won't be announced as clickable by a screen reader and can't be accessed with the tab key. Consider changing it to a button or making use of `tabindex` and `role`.

Comment: That is a very interesting remark, I was not aware of it. It will have a look at tabindex and role to make my divs reachables by screen readers and keyboards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two approaches you can take to this.

## Handle it on the div

Test to see if the click was on the edit function

```
(event) => {
    const div = event.currentTarget;
    const edit = div.querySelector('.edit');
    if (edit === event.target) {
        return;
    }
    return this.handleTrackerCardClick();
}
```

This code example makes assumptions about the DOM structure. Adjust as needed.
One of the assumptions is that the edit control is a single element with no element children. If it isn't, then you need to test to see if the click was any of the children too. Generally you would recursively check `parentNode` starting on `event.target` until you reached a match for `div` or `edit`.

## Handle it on the edit control

Call the method that stops the event from propagating up the DOM and reaching the div.

```
(event) => {
    event.stopPropagation();
    this.do_edit_thing();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this quick solution. I ended up using the 'event.stopPropagation()'

Answer (score 1):

I would simply place the inner, editable field as a sibling to the "parent". This way you can have a click handler for the outer `div` and the editable field with no overlap in terms of hierarchy.

Something like this:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div style={{ border: "1px dashed red" }}>
      <div onClick={() => console.log("outer clicked")}>Outer click</div>
      <span
        style={{ border: "1px dashed blue" }}
        onClick={() => console.log("inner clicked")}
      >
        Inner click
      </span>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Check out a working example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/throbbing-hooks-rfssu?file=/src/App.js:39-358)

Comment: But now there are large areas of the div that do nothing when you click on it.

Comment: Eh that's true in my current example, but you could add some css to stop that happening. Your answer is cleaner though 

Comment: Thank you bopbopbop for your proposition, but Quentin's solution was easier to implement :)

Comment: Yeah, agreed on that one bud :)